# When to use @await Html.PartialAsync in a View in MVC 6

Tags: razor, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I noticed on one of Scott Hanselman's blogs he uses the following code in his Views when using .Net 5 (MVC 6):

```
@await Html.PartialAsync("_LoginPartial")
```

vs.

```
@Html.Partial("_LoginPartial")
```

Is there any documentation yet on when which one should be used?

Answer (score 51):

This is actually a pretty interesting question and scenario. To a certain extent, async is the new hotness (though it's really not all that new). Entity Framework 6 hit with async methods and every... single... piece... of... documentation... suddenly starting using async for everything. I think we're seeing a little of the same here. MVC 6 supports async for things like rendering partials, so OMG we've all just *have* to use async now.

Async serves one very specific purpose. It allows the active thread to be returned to the pool to field other tasks while the current task is in a wait state. The key part of that is "wait state". Certain tasks are just flat out incompatible with async. CPU-bound work like complex financial analysis never allows the thread to enter a wait state so everything is effectively run as sync even if you set it up as async. On the other hand, things involving network latency (requesting a resource from a web API, querying a database, etc.) or that are I/O bound (reading/writing files, etc.) can at times have periods where the thread is waiting around for some other process to complete before it continues processing.

Looking specifically at rendering a partial, the only piece that's not entirely CPU-bound is reading the view file itself from the filesystem. While that's *technically* enough to make it eligible for async, how long is it really going to take to read what's essentially a text file that's probably less than 50KB max. By the time the thread is handed back to the pool, it's probably time to request it back, so you're actually using resources more inefficiently at that point.

Long and short, don't fall into the trap of "it can be done async, so I must do it async". Each use should be evaluated in terms of whether there's actually value in it. Async has a lot of overhead, and if you're only talking about a few milliseconds of wait time, it's probably not worth all that extra overhead.

Comment: Actually, `await` yields the current thread until the task completes. This has nothing to do with wait states.

Comment: First, I'm not talking specifically about the `async` keyword, just async in general here. Second, I have no idea what your last statement means. It has everything to do with being in a wait state. The thread isn't just automatically yielded. It has to do work until it's waiting on something outside of its control: data being transmitted over the wire, hard drive spinning up, whatever. Once it's not waiting on that, the code needs the thread back to complete whatever work was going on.

Comment: Chris, thanks for that well crafted response.  But I am really looking for an answer why it is being used in .net 5.  I understand what the difference between async and non-async but I still would like to know if there is a reason why he is using it for partials.  According to your answer he (Scott Hanselman) is kinda using it wrong.

Comment: Not "wrong" necessarily. Rendering partials requires hitting the filesystem. The filesystem has a queue, and depending on what else is happening on the server at the time, there might be wait time involved. Any operation that involves the potential to have to wait is eligible for async, so in that respect it's perfectly valid to have something like `PartialAsync`. My point is that in most environments and situations using async for rendering a partial will be self-defeating, and you should always evaluate *your specific scenario* when using async. Don't just use async because it's there.

Comment: just to point out: few milliseconds per thousand request is still a good gain. The fact that web apps benefits from async is much about multiple request hitting the server at the same time.

Comment: I wasn't saying that it would only save you a few milliseconds; I was saying the thread may only not be needed for a few milliseconds. If the thread is returned to the pool only to be requested back a few milliseconds later, it could actually cause the entire render time to *increase* overall, meaning your server is taking longer than it needs to to respond. Again, each use of async should be evaluated to ensure it's actually working for you and not against you. If your server has an SSD, then async for partials is going to be a total waste of resources.

Comment: *Looking specifically at rendering a partial, the only piece that's not entirely CPU-bound is reading the view file itself from the filesystem* But views can call view components which in turn can do arbitrary asynchronous operations? http://docs.asp.net/projects/mvc/en/latest/views/view-components.html

Comment: @ta.speot.is: True enough. However, that's not the point here. If you're doing async operations, then yes, use async, but the problem is that tutorials and such too often don't make a distinction and less-informed developers gain the impression that you should just use async because that's what the tutorial, book, video, etc. did. If you're just rendering a view, doing it async is probably not the right approach.

Comment: Gasp... someone turns on their head and recommends to *not* use async for everything! Rare to witness that.

Comment: @Chris what if we have a *partial view* and there is a *tag helper* or *view component* in it which makes a requests to the repository. I guess in this case we should use *RenderAsync* for rendering that *partial view*, don't we?

Comment: Yes. View components are async and if your partial is doing anything async, it it should itself be async. Honestly, you'll probably use async more often than not. I'm simply drawing the point that in certain scenarios, you might actually be better off going sync, because most developers don't actually think about it on a case by case scenario.

Comment: My question is - Is PartialAsync a substitute for an AJAX call?

Answer (score 16):

As per the ASP.NET MVC documentation on partial views.
https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/mvc/views/partial.html

> The PartialAsync method is available for partial views containing asynchronous code (although code in views is generally discouraged):

Also the note on the page.

> If your views need to execute code, the recommended pattern is to use a view component instead of a partial view.

So you should use `Partial` and avoid `PartialAsync`, and if you find yourself with a `PartialAsync` you should question yourself whether you're doing something wrong, maybe you should be using a ViewComponent instead or move the logic from the view to the controller.

Comment: Nowadays with asp.net core 2.1, the same documentation mentions _Use of the synchronous equivalents isn't recommended because there are scenarios in which they deadlock. **Future releases won't contain the synchronous methods**._

Comment: In ASP.NET 3.1 a warning is issued when using `Partial` instead of `await .. PartialAsync`, so there is not dilemma now.

Answer (score 5):

Just to keep the thread up to date for those visiting in the age of **asp.net core**.

Currently, according to the documentation:

> Partial and RenderPartial are the synchronous equivalents of PartialAsync and RenderPartialAsync, respectively. The synchronous equivalents aren't recommended because there are scenarios in which they deadlock. **The synchronous methods are targeted for removal in a future release.**

Full content:
[Partial views in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/partial?view=aspnetcore-5.0)

To get an idea about why this is an issue, you can take a look at this github entry:

https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/7083

But long story short it looks like the synchronous version of Partial simply calls async one with GetResult and that's a recipe for deadlocks in some scenarios.

To sum up, **there is no real reason not to use the Async version**. There are reasons not to use the sync ones.
Even though there is little chance to actually run into deadlocks without huge load and fancy logic within the views.... But if you do, it will be terribly hard to debug and fix.

```
var result = htmlHelper.RenderPartialAsync(partialViewName, htmlHelper.ViewData.Model, viewData: null);
result.GetAwaiter().GetResult();
```

Answer (score 3):

Necromancing.

### Option 1:

Your child partial view has some async `await` code in Razor markup - it might deadlock since MS code just calls `GetAwaiter().GetResult()` and that's a recipe for deadlocks.

**Use `PartialAsync`**

### Option 2:

Your partial view does not have any `await`s but your model-grneration code does (for example `Html.Partial("MyView.cshtml", new MyModel { PropertyX = await XyzXyz() }`) then it might also deadlock.

**Use `PartialAsync`**

### Option 3:

Your partial does not use async/await whatsoever, all the way down.

**It's OK to use `Html.Partial` (sync)**

Answer (score 2):

With regards to "await Html.PartialAsync" - this link may help you - http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/workitem/601 (follow the comments too) (as to what exactly was the problem before).

I am working on a public facing website being built on MVC 6 and "await Html.PartialAsync" is faster than "Html.Partial" - especially when the view contains lot of components.

Taking out the "await" out of Html.PartialAsync does not obviously work and Html.PartialAsync spits out the type name (ie, "System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Rendering.HtmlString]") instead of the actual view.