# Using await async in calling partials in asp mvc views

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a bunch pf partial views in my SharedViews . I have currently refactored all of the calls in the view to

```
 @await Html.PartialAsync("_PARTIALNAME")
```

There have been murmurs that devs should not just randomly add async to the code . However this code is in the view and i cant seem to find any documentation outlining the pros and cons. I would prefer to use best practices in order to produce better code.

Comment: Take a look at the answer(and comments also): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28706124/when-to-use-await-html-partialasync-in-a-view-in-mvc-6

Comment: thanks dont know why i could not find that while searching

Comment: My recommendation on this is: the best way to know if this approach works for you, it's measuring both, Partial and PartialAsync...also if you are planning your development based on scaling, with multiple server request per seconds, then is recommended to use `async` methods...