# Should I change @Html.Partial to @Html.PartialAsync as Visual Studio suggest?

Tags: c#, razor, .net-core

In my code I have `@Html.Partial("_StatusMessage", Model.StatusMessage)` but Visual Studio warning me that: `Error MVC1000: Use of IHtmlHelper.Partial may result in application deadlocks. Consider using <partial> Tag Helper or IHtmlHelper.PartialAsync.`

Should I disable this error or I should really change `@Html.Partial` to `@Html.PartialAsync`, and why?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When to use @await Html.PartialAsync in a View in MVC 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28706124/when-to-use-await-html-partialasync-in-a-view-in-mvc-6)

Answer (score 45):

Yes we should,
See below section from their official site

Migrate from an HTML Helper

Consider the following asynchronous HTML Helper example. A collection of products is iterated and displayed. Per the PartialAsync method's first parameter, the _ProductPartial.cshtml partial view is loaded. An instance of the Product model is passed to the partial view for binding.

```
CSHTML 
    @foreach (var product in Model.Products)
    {
        @await Html.PartialAsync("_ProductPartial", product)
    }
```

The following Partial Tag Helper achieves the same asynchronous rendering behavior as the PartialAsync HTML Helper. The model attribute is assigned a Product model instance for binding to the partial view.

```
CSHTML 
@foreach (var product in Model.Products)
{
    <partial name="_ProductPartial" model="product" />
}
```

Copied from
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/tag-helpers/built-in/partial-tag-helper?view=aspnetcore-2.1

Answer (score 10):

Starting with ASP.NET Core 2.1 ... use `@await Html.PartialAsync()` instead of  `@Html.Partial()`

Comment: The question asks if one should use PartialAsync and if so why. Just saying use Html.PartialAsync instead of Html.Partial() doesn't help

Comment: Although its a pretty old question and this answer is not exactly to the point what is being asked in the question but still it is a very good solution if one chooses to use Html.PartialAsync. I was having trouble and ended up with this solution which worked like a charm. Thanks Mate you saved my day. Upvoted!

Answer (score 7):

@niico, In response to your comment of

> Where does the `<partial>` tag helper fit into this?

Based on what I've been able to find, from documentation and from github it looks like you're supposed to use `@Html.PartialAsync()` or  `<partial name="_Post" />` **In Place Of** `@Html.Partial()`. However the `<partial name="" />` element doesn't seem to work on my version of .NET CORE *which is updated as of today (8/23/18)*

Please see:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/tag-helpers/built-in/partial-tag-helper?view=aspnetcore-2.1

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/partial?view=aspnetcore-2.1

https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/pull/2344

Comment: I had the same issue with the `<partial>` not working, until I found [this comment](https://github.com/aspnet/Docs/issues/6920#issuecomment-396394470)

`You're also correct that the Tag Helper has to be registered in the Views/_ViewImports.cshtml file:`

`@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers`

Answer (score 1):

I don't know your code but I think this one should anser your question:
[When to use @await Html.PartialAsync in a View in MVC 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28706124/when-to-use-await-html-partialasync-in-a-view-in-mvc-6)

As per the ASP.NET MVC documentation on partial views. https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/mvc/views/partial.html

```
The PartialAsync method is available for partial views containing asynchronous code (although code in views is generally discouraged):
```

Also the note on the page.

```
If your views need to execute code, the recommended pattern is to use a view component instead of a partial view.
```

So you should use Partial and avoid PartialAsync, and if you find yourself with a PartialAsync you should question yourself whether you're doing something wrong, maybe you should be using a ViewComponent instead or move the logic from the view to the controller.

Comment: Where does the <partial> tag helper fit into this?

Answer (score 1):

You can try this method for " Warning MVC1000 Use of IHtmlHelper.Partial " in MVC project.

[Source link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/partial?view=aspnetcore-2.1)

```css
<partial name="~/Views/Folder/_PartialName.cshtml" />
<partial name="/Views/Folder/_PartialName.cshtml" />
```