# My Bootstap modal form is covering the entire screen

Tags: asp.net-core, bootstrap-modal

I have a modal form in my ASP.NET Core 3.1 project. The problem is my modal form unexpectedly is covering entire of screen and I don't know why.

My `_Modal.cshtml`:

```
@model MyProject.CommonLayer.PublicClass.BootstrapModel

<div aria-hidden="true" aria-labelledby="@Model.AreaLabeledId" role="dialog" tabindex="-1" id="@Model.ID" class="modal fade">
    <div class="modal-dialog @Model.ModalSizeClass">
        <div class="modal-content" style="border-radius:6px;">

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

My `modal.js` file:

```
(function ($) {
function Modal() {
    var $this = this;

    function initilizeModel() {
        $("#modal-action").on('loaded.bs.modal', function (e) {

        }).on('hidden.bs.modal', function (e) {
            $(this).removeData('bs.modal');
        });
    }
    $this.init = function () {
        initilizeModel();
    }
}

$(function () {
    var self = new Modal();
    self.init();
})
}(jQuery))
```

and my `BooststrapModal.cs` file:

```
public class BootstrapModel
{
    public string ID { get; set; }
    public string AreaLabeledId { get; set; }
    public ModalSize Size { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }

    public string ModalSizeClass
    {
        get
        {
            switch (this.Size)
            {
                case ModalSize.Small:
                    return "modal-sm";

                case ModalSize.Large:
                    return "modal-lg";

                case ModalSize.Medium:
                default:
                    return "";
            }
        }
    }

    public enum ModalSize
    {
        Small,
        Large,
        Medium
    }
}
```

In the end of my `index.cs` file, for modal I put:

```
@Html.Partial("_Modal", new BootstrapModel { ID = "modal-action", Size = BootstrapModel.ModalSize.Medium })

@section AdminScripts {  
    <script src="~/js/modal/modal.js"></script>
}
```

Finally when button is clicked, the modal form covers my entire screen.
Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your `_Modal.cshtml` lose a `</div>`.I test with the code,the modal is correct.`Finaly when btn clicked, modal form cover entire of my screen.`Do you mean the dialog cover the full screen?Have you set any style for it?

Comment: Oh! Thanks. Style added and forgotten </div> also. It's working now. Thank you very much.

Comment: @YiyiYou I have an other question for my code in Index.cs (mentioned in my post). I received WARNING from VS as blew: "Use of IHtmlHelper.Partial may result in application deadlocks. Consider using <partial> Tag Helper or IHtmlHelper.PartialAsync.". What is this warning message? Would you please help me for it please?

Comment: You can refer to the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50774702/should-i-change-html-partial-to-html-partialasync-as-visual-studio-suggest).