# How do I get HTML attribute's value by TagHelper?

Tags: css, attributes, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-tag-helpers

I have a simple ASP.NET Core 2.1 tag helper, that adds `style` attribute if does not exist yet:

```
[HtmlTargetElement(Attributes = "yellow")] //contains "yellow" attribute
    public class YellowTagHelper : TagHelper
    {
       public override void Process(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output)
       {
            if (!output.Attributes.ContainsName("style"))
            {
                output.Attributes.SetAttribute("style", "color: yellow;");
            }
            else
            {
                //how to add 'color: yellow;' value, if 'style' attribute exists already?
                //or how to retrieve existing 'style' value? then I will be able to create new one
            }
       }
   }
```

And using it as follows:

```
<div class="element1" id="el1id" runat="server" yellow>
        TEST el1 //here is fine
    </div>
    <div class="element2" id="el2id" runat="server" style="background-color: pink" yellow>
        TEST el2 //here I want to add 'color: yellow;'
    </div>
```

And I am stuck with finding solution how to update style attribute's value with my tag helper.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I found what I was looking for. Solution based on [>>THIS<<](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41071757/taghelpers-add-custom-class-for-labeltaghelper-based-on-validation-attribute-re) answer, includesalready taking color from DB:

```
[HtmlTargetElement(Attributes = "yellow")] //contains "yellow" attribute
    public class YellowTagHelper : TagHelper
    {
        private ApplicationDbContext _context;

        public YellowTagHelper(ApplicationDbContext ctx)
        {
            _context = ctx;
        }
       public override void Process(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output)
       {
            var colors = _context.ColorPanels.FirstOrDefault(); //context
            var colorStyle = "color:" + colors.Element3BackgroundColor; //new color
            if (!output.Attributes.ContainsName("style"))
            {
                output.Attributes.SetAttribute("style", colorStyle);
            }
            else
            {
                var currentAttribute = output.Attributes.FirstOrDefault(attribute => attribute.Name == "style"); //get value of 'style'
                string newAttributeValue = $"{currentAttribute.Value.ToString() + "; " + colorStyle}"; //combine style values
                output.Attributes.Remove(currentAttribute); //remove old attribute
                output.Attributes.SetAttribute("style", newAttributeValue); //add merged attribute values
            }
        }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a service

```
public class ColorService
{

    public ColorService()
    {
    }

    public string GetColor()
    {
        // Add your logic here
        return "Yellow";
    }
}
```

And in you view, just inject it

```
@inject ColorService ColorService;
```

And later in the view:

```
<div class="element2" id="el2id" runat="server" style="background-color: @ColorService.GetColor()" yellow>
    TEST el2 //here I want to add 'color: yellow;'
</div>
```

You can refer to this answer for more details in case you need to add Db context into your service
[ASP.NET Core 2.1 insert CSS in layout based on data in DB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50877676/asp-net-core-2-1-insert-css-in-layout-based-on-data-in-db)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. My example could be a liitle bit confusing. It was not about the ViewBag (removed from the question). It is mostly about TagHelper replacing `style` attribute, if exists already in Razor view. I am looking for a way to merge `style` value if exists already.

Comment: @Przemyslaw.Pszemek the viewbag confused me, i think having a dynamic css class is better then replacing style in general. you can create a custom css and inject it using a service