# Net core - Html.RenderPartialAsync in for loop

Tags: asp.net-core

I'm migrating mvc web app from netfw 4.8 to net5 and I have a partial view:

```
@model List<ChatMessage>
foreach (var msg in Model)
{
    Html.RenderPartial("RenderChatMessage", msg);
}
```

Visual Studio notifies me that I might want to change that to `await Html.RenderPartialAsync`. My question is - should I do that? I'm still a bit lost in async programming. I've followed this recommendation in other places but here I would use `await` in a loop and I've read that in general that is not a good idea.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When to use @await Html.PartialAsync in a View in MVC 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28706124/when-to-use-await-html-partialasync-in-a-view-in-mvc-6)

Comment: Answers there vary. I'm rather looking for a recent view on this, considering changes in net5. @Progman

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My question is - should I do that?

The answer is yes.

We render a partial view with [RenderPartialAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/partial?view=aspnetcore-3.1#asynchronous-html-helper). This method doesn't return an `IHtmlContent`. It streams the rendered output directly to the response. Since `RenderPartialAsync` streams rendered content, it provides better performance in some scenarios. In performance-critical situations, benchmark the page using both approaches and use the approach that generates a faster response.

`Partial` and `RenderPartial` are the **synchronous** equivalents of `PartialAsync` and `RenderPartialAsync`, respectively. The synchronous equivalents aren't recommended because there are scenarios in which they deadlock. **The synchronous methods are targeted for removal in a future release.**

What will happened when render synchronously...

[image]